# Facebook like button showing up but not working

Tags: html, facebook, iframe, facebook-like, facebook-likebox

I added a fb like button to my site through the fb generated iframe. It's rendering properly but when I click on it a pop-up appears and automatically closes after a few seconds and nothing happens. It's not liking anything. When I opened the page on my mobile and tried to like, thee button just turned into red text saying 'Error'. This is my iframe's code:

```
<iframe src="//www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=http%3A%2F%2FmyDomain.com&amp;width&amp;layout=button_count&amp;action=like&amp;show_faces=false&amp;share=false&amp;height=21&amp;appId=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; height:21px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
```

I double-checked that I added the correct app ID, my app is not in testing mode and is open to the public. I also have the right domain set in the app's settings. Can some one tell me what I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

Facebook provides the like button with their own generated code(at least 2 years ago they were) 
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/like-button (I'm at work so I don't know this is the right page,I can't open the page)

But their code should do the trick.

Comment: The iframe i'm using IS fb generated. Sorry for not mentioning that earlier. I updated the question.

Comment: well then there must be a problem within facebook code or something. I think you should contact the facebook help.